# calculate percentage of two select counts

Tags: oracle

I have a query like

```
select count(1) from table_a where state=1;
```

it gives 20

```
select count(1) from table_a where state in (1,2);
```

it gives 25

I would like to have a query to extract percentage 80% (will be 20*100/25).
Is possible to have these in only one query?

Comment: `count(*)` is the standard SQL expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think without testing that the following SQL command can do that

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN STATE = 1      THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
      /SUM(CASE WHEN STATE IN (1,2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
      as PERCENTAGE
FROM TABLE_A
```

or the following

```
SELECT S1 / (S1 + S2) as S1_PERCENTAGE
FROM
    (
    SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN STATE = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as S1
          ,SUM(CASE WHEN STATE = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as S2
    FROM TABLE_A
    )
```

or the following

```
SELECT S1 / T as S1_PERCENTAGE
FROM
    (
    SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN STATE = 1      THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as S1
          ,SUM(CASE WHEN STATE IN (1,2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as T
    FROM TABLE_A
    )
```

you have the choice for performance or readability !

Answer (score 1):

Just as a slight variation on @schlebe's first query, you can continue to use `count()` by making that conditional:

```
select count(case when state = 1 then state end)
     / count(case when state in (1, 2) then state end) as result
from table_a
```

or multiplying by 100 to get a percentage instead of a decimal:

```
select 100 * count(case when state = 1 then state end)
           / count(case when state in (1,2) then state end) as percentage
from table_a
```

Count ignores nulls, and both of the case expressions default to null if their conditions are not met (you could have `else null` to make it explicit too).

Quick demo with a CTE for dummy data:

```
with table_a(state) as (
            select 1 from dual connect by level <= 20
  union all select 2 from dual connect by level <= 5
  union all select 3 from dual connect by level <= 42
)
select 100 * count(case when state = 1 then state end)
           / count(case when state in (1,2) then state end) as percentage
from table_a;

PERCENTAGE
----------
        80
```

Answer (score 0):

Why the plsql tag? Regardless, i think what you need is:

```
(select count(1) from table_a where state=1) * 100 /  (select count(1) from table_a where state in (1,2)) from dual
```

Comment: You need another layer of `select` that uses those two queries as column expressions - you have the `from dual` part but not its `select` or the necessary parentheses.

Comment: I don't need another select. Those queries return scalar values. I've added the parentheses for better reading.

Comment: Your edited code will still get ORA-00933. You need the keyword `select` before what you have now - to go with the `from dual` at the end.